# Get google plus followers using cordova ionic 2

Tags: android, angular, ionic2, google-plus

I am new to Angular2 and Ionic2.
I have been developing an android application with Firebase (angular-fire2) and Ionic2.

In app, integrated google login with [cordova plugin google plus](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-plus/)
from ionic native and getting userId, idToken, etc.

With those values I am creating firebase credential and authenticating with firebase succesfully.

But my problem is how can I get followers list of currently logged user?

I have seen two google API's,

1.Google Plus Web API

2.Google People API

But these two are not giving followers.

Please, Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to use a [**Google People API**](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list).

**Method:** `people.connections.list`

> Provides a list of the authenticated user's contacts merged with any
>   linked profiles.

***Http Request***

```
https://people.googleapis.com/v1/{resourceName=people/*}/connections
```

***Response JSON***

```
{
  "connections": [
    {
      object(Person)
    }
  ],
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "nextSyncToken": string,
  "totalPeople": number,
}
```

Comment: Hi! Sampath. Thanks for user response. I have tried your code with `people/me`. But, it won't for me. This shows the error message `Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.` with code `401`.

Comment: Have you done this basic API settings? https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus#3-google-api-setup

Comment: Yes, I did same like that. Google login also working fine. Is this worked for u?